# collective.z3cform.datetimewidget woes

Tags: datetime, plone

I am trying to extend a form and have added a Datetime field to it. When I assign a datetime.datetime value to the widget inside updateWidgets(), it throws an error saying datetime does not have **getitem**.

I have got around this by patching widget_datetime and widget_date inside this package to check if self.value is a datetime and act accordingly.

Are there some advanced examples of using this Datetime Field in a form?

Comment: Can you explain why do you want to do that and paste your code also?

Comment: I was able to get around this by saving the datetime as a timetuple() in my content object. We cannot store directly as it causes the getitem problem.

Comment: I was able to get around this by saving the datetime using its timetuple() method in my content object. We cannot store directly as it causes the getitem problem. The day(), month() and year() methods in widget_date.py try to read from self.value[0,1,2] and if self.value is a datetime this fails with the no _getitem_ error.

Comment: See code here https://gist.github.com/sureshvv/a89da9640254f403b399

See how I have used timetuple() to get around the issue of subscripting datetime values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use timetuple() method of datetime when saving to the context object. See the gist in the comments section above.